# Adding arguments to HTML link to a local file in an email

Tags: email, arguments

Is there any way to add arguments to a file:/// call within an email? Ideally I'd like my recipients to be able to click a link that would launch a program with some extra arguments. Thus far I know I can do an HTML link like `<a href="file:///C:/path/to/program.exe">ClickMe!</a>` but if I try adding arguments, it cannot find the file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to pass query parameters via a URL is using a question mark, followed by key/value pairs, each separated with an ampersand:

file:///C:/path/to/program.exe?a=b&c=d

I have no idea if the browser will pass those query parameters to the executable.  I believe this will depend on the browser / os combination...

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not passing arguments through a browser URL, for the most part the recipients are using Outlook, so adding url-like key/value pairs doesn't work.